# PHP: Writing unique random number to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I am trying to write a serial and random PIN to mysql database but some PIN values are written multiple times.

how do I skip writing $pin into pin column if it already exist?

The snippet follows:

```
<?php

for($serial = 1000; $serial <= 1600; $serial++) {
    $serial_prefix = "HCIS";

    //generate random figures.
    $rand_pin1 = rand(10599, 99999);
    $rand_pin2 = rand(22222, 89898);
    $pin = $rand_pin1 . $rand_pin2;
    $f_serial = $serial_prefix . $serial;

    $check = "SELECT pin FROM pin_serial WHERE pin = '$pin'";
    $check_query = mysqli_query($connection, $check);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_query) > 0){
        // how do I skip writing $pin into pin column if it already exist here

    } 
    elseif(mysqli_num_rows($check_query) == 0){
        //inserting a generated figure and $serial into serial and pin column.
        $pin_serial_query = "INSERT INTO pin_serial (serial, pin) VALUES('$f_serial', '$pin')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $pin_serial_query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A do..while loop should solve your problem:

```
for ( $serial = 1000; $serial <= 1600; $serial++ ) {

  $serial_prefix = "HCIS";

  do {

    // generate random figures
    $rand_pin1 = rand( 10599, 99999 );
    $rand_pin2 = rand( 22222, 89898 );
    $pin = $rand_pin1 . $rand_pin2;
    $f_serial = $serial_prefix . $pin;

    $check = "SELECT pin FROM pin_serial WHERE pin = '$pin'";
    $check_query = mysqli_query( $connection, $check );

  } while ( mysqli_num_rows( $check_query ) >0 );

  //inserting a generated figure and $serial into serial and pin column.
  $pin_serial_query = "INSERT INTO pin_serial ( serial, pin ) VALUES ( '$f_serial', '$pin' )";
  mysqli_query( $connection, $pin_serial_query );

}
```

While this will solve your immediate issue, as the number of rows grows you'll end up sending more and more SQL requests until you find an unused PIN. You will likely be happier with the result if you allow mySQL to generate a unique PIN for each new row.

Comment: When I tried your solution, almost all the pin values are the same. It did not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry... stupid mistake on my part. Change "$f_serial = $serial_prefix . $serial;" to "$f_serial = $serial_prefix . $pin;" and it will work. I've corrected this in the answer.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Create unique index for `pin` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `pin_serial` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`pin`)
```

Then change your query to

```
INSERT INTO pin_serial (serial, pin) VALUES('$f_serial', '$pin')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE serial_pin = VALUES(serial_pin)
```

(note `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE serial_pin = VALUES(serial_pin)` part, this is just example, you can just pin=pin to skip) It will update query if row with that pin value already exists, or insert a new row.

You also can use `INSERT IGNORE` statement, which will just ignore duplicates.

[More about INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) in [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) on topic

Please note that in your example, the script is vulnerable to **[Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** attack. To avoid it, you should first pass your parameters to [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function to make the data inside sql-safe(by escaping ambiguous characters)

Comment: Good idea, but I'll add a warning about the **SQL injection risk** (even if it seem to be Pi/arduino local code)

Comment: @Blag good point, added note about sql injection to the answer.

Comment: The pin and serial column are already a unique key. I tried the solution you provided but still got multiple pin written.

Comment: @user3186314 do you have `unique index(pin, serial_pin)`? Then you must have __unique pair__, that is, error will occur only if you insert existing combination of serial and serial_pin. You need to change to have two unique indexes then.

Comment: Pin and serial are unique. I was suprised when I saw duplicates in the pin column.

Comment: You need to have separate indexes for each of them otherwise they won't be unique as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write the serial into the row where the pin generated pin already sits (effectively overwriting the old serial that is already there, you would use an UPDATE statement:

```
... "UPDATE pin_serial SET serial='$serial'";
```

If you just want to skip this pin/serial combo I think yo already got the answer. Your code should work